# How to set file contents but leaving permissions alone using Puppet?

Tags: permissions, puppet

I'm using the [`file`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/file.html) directive to set the contents of many configuration files. Some of the applications have their own configuration interfaces which are the preferred way to modify these files (before copying them back to Puppet). But some of these applications also **change the mode of the configuration files when saving them.** Because I can't be bothered to record and keep up to date hundreds of file to mode settings which are irrelevant to the configuration this leads to a fight between Puppet and the application, each overriding the other's mode. Which in turn leads to a longer Puppet run than necessary and to more clutter in the logs. So how do I simply **leave the mode alone?**

To be clear, I *do* want to replace contents, so `replace => false` is not an option.

Comment: Don't set the `mode` property on the file resource? If you're already not setting it, then please include the manifest + agent log.

Comment: If that's the way to do it I need to know how to unset an inherited value, because there is one in the top level manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comment, if the `mode` property of the `file` resource is set in a base class and you wish to override it, then use `undef`:

```
class specialist inherits base {
  File["/etc/example"] {
    content => "new content",
    mode    => undef,
  }
}
```

The `mode` property will then be *unmanaged* and won't be changed by Puppet.

Comment: Just discovered this; thanks! I've filed an [issue to document this](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-7415).

Comment: The mode for newly created files should be 0644 I think, irrespective of the umask, but then all unspecified (or `undef`) properties will not be actively managed by the agent during a run.